# Multilingual project using JetBrains IntelliJ IDEA or other tools

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

Trying to start multilingual project where Java, C & C++ will be used mixed.

With NetBeans I could have all the necessary plugins at ones. Trying to figure out how and which JetBrains tools I could use.

Any help will be gratefully appreciated.

P.S. I am having a license for the full stack of JetBrains tools.

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA + CLion I believe.

Comment: Of course IDEA +CLion alongside is an obvious choice. Except small thing they don't recognize each other project structure so as syntax and libs. And I would prolly survive with C & C++ syntax highlighting and analyses if there is such an option. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

You'll be using Jetbrains IntelliJ and CLion side by side since they are more specialize in that languages.

Also you can use IntelliJ alone and use some plugins todo works on other language.

As of now, I'm doing both frontend(Vuejs) and backend(Django) on a daily basis, and I use both Webstorm and PyCharm in this type of development.

Comment: AFAIK PyCharm Pro includes all stuff from WebStorm (you may just need to install some plugins manually as they are not bundled by default).

Comment: Thank you. And "some plugin" suggestion will be very-very much appreciated. Ideally if Jetbrains came up with an idea of having CLion as a plugin of kind that'd be a game changer. But .... It's just a dream.